# Connect to aws ec2 node by websocket

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, websocket, web3js, go-ethereum

I have created a chain node on aws ec2 instance using geth.
Do I need to enable something or what ip should I use to connect to it?
I am using web3.js using new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss_address', abiOptions)

I enabled ws for it using --ws. Where I got "WebSocket enabled url=ws://127.0.0.0.1:8546".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this command:

```
nohup ./geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node  --cache 8500 --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0  --ws --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" --ws.origins "*" --ws.api "web3, eth" &
```

And this line to connect:

```
new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://yourPublicIpAddress:8546', abiOptions)
```

All working, thanks for support)))

P.S. In my case, it was the connection with PORT specification that worked. And only through ws, not wss. And I didn't notice any difference when connecting via IP with or without DNS

Answer (score 0):

From the Geth [docs page](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/command-line-options) on command-line options:

```
--ws                                (default: false)                   ($GETH_WS)
      Enable the WS-RPC server

--ws.addr value                     (default: "localhost")             ($GETH_WS_ADDR)
      WS-RPC server listening interface

--ws.api value                                                         ($GETH_WS_API)
      API's offered over the WS-RPC interface

--ws.origins value                                                     ($GETH_WS_ORIGINS)
      Origins from which to accept websockets requests

--ws.port value                     (default: 8546)                    ($GETH_WS_PORT)
      WS-RPC server listening port

--ws.rpcprefix value                                                   ($GETH_WS_RPCPREFIX)
      HTTP path prefix on which JSON-RPC is served. Use '/' to serve on all paths.
```

---

If you only specify the `--ws` option, the default value of `--ws.addr` is used and the node listens for incoming requests only from the local machine.

You can specify the network interface, which the node listens on, by its IP address or hostname. For example if your server's IP is `123.123.123.123`, you can specify the following IP. This enables the node to accept WS connections **to this IP**.

```
geth --ws --ws.addr "123.123.123.123"
```

Or you want to listen to incoming requests from all network interfaces of the server (e.g. localhost, all LAN cables, VPN tunnel, wifi, ...), you can specify the value of `--ws.addr` as `0.0.0.0`. This enables the node to accept all incoming WS connections.

```
geth --ws --ws.addr "0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: Ok, if i have ec2 instance with ip 123..123.123.123, adn i added this args to command --ws --ws.addr "0.0.0.0", how i can connect to it?
Just by using new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://123.123.123.123:8546', abiOptions)?

Comment: @ObscuRUS Assuming all other parameters are correctly set up, your client machine has visibility on the server, the server's firewall is not blocking the connection, etc., then you'll be able to open the websocket connection with the node.

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me which of the possible ip's I should use? (private, public, or some other kind)

Comment: @ObscuRUS It depends on your use case. But generally, if you want to be able to connect to the node using a public network, use the public IP.

Comment: I have tried using public IPv4 and IPv4 DNS addresses, but still nothing works. In the security group all traffic is allowed.
P.S. Do I need to specify the port I get from geth and which ip (dns or not) to prefer?

Comment: I found [articles](https://saturncloud.io/blog/setting-up-wss-websockets-on-aws-ec2-instance-a-comprehensive-guide/) where they talk about using nginx to create a server. Is it necessary or should everything work without it?

Comment: @ObscuRUS Nginx might be needed as a reverse proxy in some scenarios - e.g. if the Geth ports are not exposed by the server and you need to route the trafic elsewhere; or if you run multiple Geth instances on the server... If you don't specify the port in the Geth cli options, the default port is used... This seems like a broader issue with your setup, and I don't have all the information to be able to troubleshoot it, but I recommend trying it always locally first to test if it works on the Geth side. After this is confirmed, then you can move to sending the requests from an external client.

Comment: All right, thank you. How do I check if the socket is working locally?
Also, what do you say about the ip selection I described above?